# Redirect to existing view from Controller in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3

I'm redirecting to a view from controller and that is ok but if view doesn't exist it returns blank page so how to resolve that?

```
class PagesController extends Controller    
{
public function show(Request $request)
  {
 $showpage = $request->input('search'); // Request object
     if (View::exists('pages.'.$showpage)) {
     return view('pages.'.$showpage);
   }
      else {
       return ;
   }  
  }  
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do if the view doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to render something if the controller was not found, it would be a good idea to render an error page. You could create an error page in resources/errors, and then render it.

Try this out with the default 503.blade.php template and then, create your own.

```
class PagesController extends Controller    
{
public function show(Request $request)
  {
 $showpage = $request->input('search'); // Request object
     if (View::exists('pages.'.$showpage)) {
     return view('pages.'.$showpage);
   }
      else {
       return response()->view('errors.503');
   }  
  }  
}
```

Comment: What I want is to stay on same page and do nothing if view doesn't exist, I could render error page but it's better to not going anywhere.

Comment: In this case, you could use: `return redirect()->back();` to redirect to the same view. But if you want to stay on the same page without being redirected, you should change your view code to use an ajax request to check if the view is valid, before calling `show`.

Answer (score 0):

simple you can redirect exiting page with **return back();** in laravel 5.6

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following if you want to stay on the same page

```
return redirect()->back();
```